# Run both 32-bit and 64-bit tests in the same run?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, mstest

I'm running unit tests using the Resharper test runner in VS2013 and MSTest.  I have one assembly that's set to AnyCPU, and I have a case where I want to run some unit tests against that both loaded as a 32-bit assembly and as a 64-bit assembly.

The reason for this is that there are some `DllImport` external functions in the Windows API and if I don't get the interop `struct`s defined just right, it will work in one and not the other.

So I created two unit test DLLs, one set to x86 and the other to x64, and they both reference the DLL under test.

I see in Resharper where I can point it to the Local.testsettings file.  Then in the Local.testsettings file, there is a drop down on the Hosts page called "Run tests in 32 bit or 64 bit process" and I can select either "Force tests to run in 32 bit process" or "Run tests in 64 bit process on 64 bit machine".  Unfortunately all you can do is switch back and forth between these two options, so either one set of tests fail, or the other set fails.

What I really want to do is run it based on the platform target of the unit test assembly.  Any way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

What you request isn't possible with MSTest AFAIK. You can use a test platform that is capable of parallel execution, like [Nuclear.Test](https://github.com/MikeLimaSierra/Nuclear.Test). It executes all tests on various runtimes and processor architectures.